# What makes my custom HashTable slow and how can I improve it?

Tags: ruby, data-structures

I am currently making my own HashTable in ruby for educational purposes and find it to be slow.

First and foremost, let me show you the little test I made to benchmark it with ruby built-in `Hash` with a word counter over 30 [lorem ipsum](https://fr.lipsum.com/feed/html) paragraphs.

```rb
ht = {}
lorem = File.open("lorem.txt")

lorem.readlines.map(&:chomp).each do |line|
    line.tr('.,','').split(" ").each do |word|
    value = ht[word]
    if value
      ht[word] = value+1
    else
      ht[word] = 1
    end
    end
end

#puts "vitae => #{ht["vitae"]}"
```

We get the correct result: 34.

Now, let's benchmark this with hyperfine

```bash
$ hyperfine --warmup 3 --runs 10 'ruby HashTableBuiltin.rb'
Benchmark 1: ruby HashTableBuiltin.rb
  Time (mean ± σ):      88.0 ms ±   5.2 ms    [User: 66.7 ms, System: 17.5 ms]
  Range (min … max):    80.5 ms …  98.2 ms    10 runs
```

This code roughly runs in `88 ms`.

---

Ok, so now it is time for my ultra slow HashTable. I decided to go with [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing) and [djb2](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/%7Eoz/hash.html).

```rb
class HashBucket
    public attr_reader :key, :value

    public def initialize(key, value)
        @key   = key
        @value = value
    end
end

class HashTable
    public def initialize(capacity = 64)
        @length   = 0
        @capacity = capacity
        @buckets  = Array.new(capacity)
    end

    public def []=(key,value)
        insert(key,value)
    end

    public def [](key)
        get(key)
    end

    private def extend_capacity
        @capacity = @capacity == 0 ? 1 : @capacity*2

        new_buckets = Array.new(@capacity)
        @capacity.times do |i|
            new_buckets[i] = @buckets[i]
        end

        @buckets = new_buckets
    end

    private def ratio
        @length.to_f / @capacity.to_f
    end

    public def insert(key, value)
      get_index   = get_index(key)
      key_index   = djb2(key) & (@capacity - 1)
      new_bucket  = HashBucket.new(key, value)

      if ratio >= 0.7
        extend_capacity
      end

      if get_index
          @buckets[get_index] = new_bucket
      else
        @capacity.times do
          key_index = (key_index + 1) & (@capacity - 1) if (@buckets[key_index] != nil)
        end

        @buckets[key_index] = new_bucket
        @length += 1
      end
    end

    public def get(key)
      key_index   = djb2(key) & (@capacity - 1)

      @capacity.times do
          if (@buckets[key_index] != nil) && (@buckets[key_index].key == key)
              return @buckets[key_index].value
          else
              key_index = (key_index + 1) & (@capacity - 1)
          end
      end

      nil
    end

    public def get_index(key)
      key_index   = djb2(key) & (@capacity - 1)

      @capacity.times do
          if (@buckets[key_index] != nil) && (@buckets[key_index].key == key)
              return key_index
          else
              key_index = (key_index + 1) & (@capacity - 1)
          end
      end

      nil
    end

    # http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html
    protected def djb2(key)
        hash = 5381

        key.each_byte do |c|
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c
        end

        hash
    end
end
```

Now, by just replacing the line

```rb
ht = {}
```

by

```rb
ht = HashTable.new
```

in the test we get the same behavior in order to redo it.

```bash
hyperfine --warmup 3 --runs 10 'ruby HashTable.rb' 'ruby HashTableBuiltin.rb'
Benchmark 1: ruby HashTable.rb
  Time (mean ± σ):     234.2 ms ±   4.8 ms    [User: 210.0 ms, System: 18.7 ms]
  Range (min … max):   225.9 ms … 242.5 ms    10 runs

Benchmark 2: ruby HashTableBuiltin.rb
  Time (mean ± σ):      86.5 ms ±   2.7 ms    [User: 65.0 ms, System: 17.8 ms]
  Range (min … max):    81.4 ms …  89.9 ms    10 runs

Summary
  ruby HashTableBuiltin.rb ran
    2.71 ± 0.10 times faster than ruby HashTable.rb
```

So here it is. `2.7` times slower. What can I do to improve it?

Comment: Write it in C like the original?

Comment: rewrite it in C?

Comment: I do not wanna make it as fast as the built-in C version. I just wanna to make it as fast as possible while keeping it in ruby.

Comment: Here's a nice article that should help with your implementation: https://www.engineyard.com/blog/hash-lookup-in-ruby-why-is-it-so-fast/ and then there's always [Rubinius](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/hash.rb)

Comment: If you want to improve your current coffee, profile it and see where it’s taking time. I’d be a little surprised if it got significantly faster.

Comment: 2.7 times slower doesn't sound that bad for pure Ruby vs C.

Comment: Well, in fact this is way slower since running an empty ruby program takes approximately `85 ms` on my computer… This is clearly visible when using `benchmark`: for the built-in `Hash` I get `0.001424   0.000129   0.001553 (  0.001543)` and for my custom `HashTable` I get `0.186166   0.000680   0.186846 (  0.187678)`. More than 100 times slower.

Comment: Even your Ruby is slower than it needs to be. You should be using Array#tally rather than rolling your own loops. More importantly, do you understand that most of Ruby core is implemented in C? And that an interpreter like Ruby interprets certain code when it loads the file, not just when executing it, so comparing it to an "empty" program is meaningless? It also looks like you're trying to do some iterative memory allocation in a language that doesn't really support direct memory access, so you're making life hard on yourself by expecting to do C-like things in interpreted Ruby.